# cannot attach and step into to a wcf process debugging on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, wcf, ide, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, when I try to attach to a proccess (F11) it doesn't step into the method of wcf Service and doesn't ask me if i want to attach...it just goes on.

So i have installed VS2017, same solution, same projects... everything works normal, perfectly.

What can i do to let Visual studio 2019 Debug works?

at first first start of the solution, i received this message

Error - The security debugging option is set but it requires the Visual Studio
hosting process which is unavailable in this debugging configuration. The
security debugging option will be disabled. This option may be re-enabled in
the Security property page. The debugging session will continue without security
debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably due to the new debugging method on vs2017/2019...

I solved by unisntalling 2019 then installing 2015 and then reinstalling 2019.

I know is not the best way but i was risking to be late on projects.. maybe can help someone